# how to create a routine in R for 4 tables with same name changing just the last character

Tags: r, for-loop

The idea is to do something like this:

```
for(i in 1:4){
paste0("tabDummy",i) <- data.frame(data[,c(1,i+1)],colnames(data)[i+1])
}
```

But I know that paste0 would return a character of the way:

```
"tabDummy1" or "tabDummy2" ...
```

instead of just:

```
tabDummy1 or tabDummy2 ...
```

which are in fact the names of the tables I would like to work with in my rountine.

Is there a function would do what I am thinking?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this....

```
for(i in 1:4){
    assign(paste0("tabDummy",i), data.frame(data[,c(1,i+1)],colnames(data)[i+1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `R` way would be to make a list with four elements that could then be manipulated however you'd like, instead of four distinctly named elements.

```
tabDummy <- list()
for(i in 1:4){
   tabDummy[[i]] <- data.frame(data[, c(1, i+1)], colnames(data)[i+1])
}
```

Or if you wanted to use the `lapply` function, which is built for working with lists...

```
tabDummy <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {
   data.frame(data[, c(1, i+1)], colnames(data)[i+1])
})
```

Or, it seems you're actually converting the data set from wide to long format; there are a multitude of questions here about that, one method would be as follows; this first creates a single long data frame, and then splits it.

```
data_long <- reshape2::melt(id.vars=1, measure.vars=2:5)
tabDummy <- split(data_long, data_long$variable)
```